# Ant javadoc produces no result when using fileset

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I am trying to put together an ant javadoc task that would use nested fileset and can't get it to output anything.

Here is what I have

```
    <target name="javadoc_all"  description="">
    <cleanDir dir="${buildWorkingDir}/Javadocs/all" />

    <javadoc destdir="${buildWorkingDir}/Javadocs/all" classpathref="path4javadoc" Verbose="true"
             maxmemory="2048m" useexternalfile="yes" failonerror="no">
        <fileset dir="${buildInputDir}/Java/src" defaultexcludes="yes" casesensitive="no">
            <include name="com/pckg/**"/>
            <exclude name="**/test/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

On the output I get a bunch of "[javadoc] Loading source file" then it ends with build success and nothing being output

If I use sourcepath on javadoc directive to set the source everything works, but then I am not able to control the inclusion/exclusion list.

I am using jdk 1.8.0_102

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: May be you want to try without `defaultexcludes` attribute?

Comment: Thank you, no change, same result.

Comment: Did more experimenting, it seems like fileset only works if the number of files it covers is small. For a limited set the javadoc gets generated, once I go above certain number it fails, no error is displayed.

Comment: Try to run in debug mode and see there are any hints.

Comment: Looks like packageset does mostly of what I need. It allows excluding on a package/folder level. It does not let you pick individual files to be excluded though. It also seems to work no matter how many files are involved.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution ended up using multiple packagesets

```
        <packageset dir="${buildInputDir}/Java/src">
            <include name="**"/>
            <exclude name="**/test*/**"/>
        </packageset>
        <packageset dir="${buildInputDir}/MoreSourceFiles/src">
            <include name="**"/>
            <exclude name="**/test*/**"/>
        </packageset>
```

This is not ideal as it does not allow excluding by file name, only by package name, but it was closest to what I needed.